# Cypress Test: finds no <li> element

Tags: wordpress, testing, automated-tests, cypress

i am trying to select this item from this list but it says it doesn't exist
[image]

this is the html structure:

```
<span class="select2-results">
<ul class="select2-results__options" role="listbox" tabindex="-1" id="select2-billing_country-results" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false" aria-activedescendant="select2-billing_country-result-jqjd-AS">
<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-billing_country-result-klqe-default" role="option" data-selected="false" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false">Seleziona un Paese/una regione…</li>
<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-billing_country-result-gzkv-AX" role="option" data-selected="false" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false">Åland Islands</li>
<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-billing_country-result-n44m-AF" role="option" data-selected="true" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false">Afghanistan</li>
......
```

with cypress I use these commands:

```
cy.get('#select2-billing_country-container').click()
cy.get('li#select2-billing_country-result-c98f-default').click()
```

but i get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the texts at the end of the id is changing every time the DOM is loaded, so you need to select a locator which tackles that problem, one option would be instead of checking the entire id we will check the part of the id, and then click on the third element.

```
cy.get('li[id*="select2-billing_country"]').eq(2).click()
```